# Eigendecomposition of $M_{ij} = A_{ij} - \frac{1}{N}(\sum_k A_{kj} + \sum_k A_{ik}) + \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{kl} A_{kl}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a square, symmetric real matrix $A = (A_{ij}) \in \mathbb R^{N\times N}$, with known eigenvectors and eigenvalues, can we say something about the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of:

$$M_{ij} = A_{ij} - \frac{1}{N}\left(\sum_k A_{kj} + \sum_k A_{ik}\right) + \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{kl} A_{kl}$$

Clearly $M_{ij}$ is also symmetric and thus has an eigendecomposition. The last term is a rank-one update and I know how to handle that ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman–Morrison_formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula)). The other terms are also low-rank updates, but combining everything together (I tried Woodbury formula) seems to get very messy, and I think I'm missing some shortcut here.

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer** Let $\mathbf J$ be the matrix with all ones and $$\mathbf K = \mathbf I_N - \frac1{N}\mathbf J$$

$\mathbf K$ is an orthogonal projection indeed, $\mathbf K^{\intercal} =\mathbf K$ and $$\mathbf K^2 = \mathbf I - \frac2N \mathbf J + \frac1{N^2}\mathbf J^2 = \mathbf K$$

In fact it is the orthogonal projection of the hyperplane $\left\{\boldsymbol{x} : \mathbf 1^\intercal \boldsymbol{x} = 0\right\}$. It is not that hard to prove that:
\begin{align}
M = \mathbf K^{\intercal} A\mathbf K
\end{align}

This proves that $\mathbf 1$ is an eigenvector of $M$ associated with $\lambda = 0$. Now if $A = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \lambda_i\boldsymbol{u}_i\boldsymbol{u}_i^\intercal$,

$$M = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \lambda_i \mathbf K \boldsymbol{u}_i \left(\mathbf K\boldsymbol{u}_i\right)^{\intercal}.$$

Comment: I am still checking the details of your calculation, but I fail to see why it's "partial"? Seems that your last equation gives the **full** answer to my question, or am I missing something?

Comment: Ah! The new vectors $K u_i$ are *not* orthogonal. We still have to diagonalize your last expression ... That's what's missing.

Comment: Btw this is called a matrix congruence. I presume Sylvester law of inertia should say something here about the number of eigenvalues of $M$ of each sign ... after removing somehow the hyperplane orthogonal to $\mathbf 1$ (because the law of inertia would apply only if $K$ were invertible) ... only an intuition.

Comment: Yes I was checking that as well

Comment: I should mention that I'm mostly interested in the largest and smallest eigenvalue / eigenvector pairs of $M$.

Comment: In that case you can try to use quadratic optimization with single linear constraint

Comment: Numerically is no problem to find it. But I was hoping for some analytical understanding.

Comment: Yes I am speaking about analytical understanding.